# finally() not working in Vuejs another app

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, axios

Recently I did [this](https://github.com/Hujjat/laravStart) tutorial.

In this app I can successfully run a vuejs app and `axios.then.catch.finally` or `this.form.then.catch.finally`.

But I added npm to my old project that was recently upgraded to laravel 5.7.
In my app I can't add `finally` function. If i do, it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: axios.post(...).then(...).catch(...).finally is not a function

My app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

// require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue'
window.Vue = Vue
window.axios = require('axios');
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'
window.Form = Form;

Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)

Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));
//select 2
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)

//sweet alert 1
import swal1 from 'sweetalert';
window.swal1 = swal1;

import swal from 'sweetalert2'
window.swal = swal;
const toast = swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 3000
});
window.toast = toast;

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue ap
 *
 *
 * plication instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('timetable-component', require('./components/TimetableComponent.vue'))   

/* filter active and inactive */ 
Vue.filter('activeInactive', function (value) {
    if(value==1){
        return 'Active'
    }else{
        return 'Inactive'
    }
})

const app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    data:{

    },
    methods:{

    },
    mounted(){

    }
});
```

I think my app.js is exactly the same as the tutorial app.js for Form request.
Another thing is that in the tutorial he did not use axios import anywhere but he smoothly used it. But without import, I can't use `axios.then`. 
How did he use it without importing axios?
How can I use `finally` with `then.catch`?

a componenet:

```
loadSite() {
  axios
    .get("/api/site/list")
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.siteList = data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }).finally(()=>{ 

    });
},
```

Comment: Why are you loading `vue` twice? One from `import Vue from 'vue'` and the other from `require('vue')`?

Comment: In the video tutorial i found this.@RuChernChong

Comment: You don't have to do it twice. Just use `import Vue from 'vue'` and `window.Vue = Vue`

Comment: Current : `import Vue from 'vue'
window.Vue = Vue
window.axios = require('axios');
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'
window.Form = Form;` But still raising the same error! @RuChernChong

Comment: Please post your full code ?

Comment: did you find any solutions ?

Comment: Yes. See approved answer below. Install the package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [document](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/405fe690f93264d591b7a64d006314e2222c8727/COOKBOOK.md#promiseprototypefinally), to make `finally` works, you need to add `promise.prototype.finally`

```
npm install axios promise.prototype.finally --save
```

and then

```
const axios = require('axios');
require('promise.prototype.finally').shim();

axios
  .get('http://www.example.com/user')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    return response;
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log('this will always be called');
  });
```

Comment: But in the tutorial i did not see anything like that! How he did this without using  `npm install axios promise.prototype.finally --save` ? @ittus

Comment: where i need to add this code : const axios = require('axios'); ......?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, just solved it by includeing this file

`<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise.prototype.finally" defer></script>`

Comment: where did you add this ?